# Update panel for Treeview control in asp.net not working?

Tags: asp.net, .net, treeview, asp.net-ajax

On clicking the nodes in Treeview, i construct the HTML in code behind and load it in my literal control. I do not want the page to load each time I click any of the nodes in tree view control to fetch the data for showing it in literal. How can I avoid postback here ?
I tried using updatepanel around treeview as shown below, and now the data is not changing on clicking different nodes and there is not postback. How can i solve this ?

```
                            <table> 
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top">
                                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_HealthCon_Ddl_Conditions" runat="server">
                                            <contenttemplate>
                                      <asp:TreeView ID="Tree_Index" NodeWrap="false" Style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;" runat="server" Width="10px" EnableClientScript="False">
                                        </asp:TreeView>
                                         </contenttemplate> 
                                         </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>


                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <asp:Label ID="litSPName" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Literal ID="lit_basic_Result" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added the contenttemplate and updatepanel to my tables and it worked !!!